# Multiple WebGrid on a single view updating all WebGrid on any action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have 2 WebGrid on a Single View which are using same model. Now the problem is that whenever I apply sorting on a single webgrid, it is also sorting another webgrid. I am using fieldNamePrefix still having problem. Here is my code:

**1st Partial View:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<CRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Dashboard_Requests>>" %>
<%    
     var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID",fieldNamePrefix:"grid2", canSort: true);%>
<%=
        grid.GetHtml( htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid2" },tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader", columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID", header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
                 grid.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Created_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
         ))
   %>
```

**2nd Partial View:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Dashboard_Requests>>" %>
 <%    
     var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID",fieldNamePrefix:"grid1", canSort: true);%>
     <%=
        grid.GetHtml( htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid1" },tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader", columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID", header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
                 grid.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Created_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
         ))
   %>
```

Comment: why dont you create seperate files for both of the partial views ? You can call those partial views from your single view page. Use `@Html.Partial("_par1",Model)` inside your view with in your `<div></div>` tags to render them.

Comment: @Karthik I have created separate files for both partial views but both uses same model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is property named "ajaxUpdateContainerId" in webgrid. This property could help you to solve your problem.

1st partial view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<CRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Dashboard_Requests>>" %>
<%    
 var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID",fieldNamePrefix:"grid2", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId:"FirstDiv");%>
<div id="FirstDiv">
<%=
    grid1.GetHtml( htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid2" },tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader", columns: grid.Columns(
      grid1.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID", header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
     grid1.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
     grid1.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
     grid1.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
     grid1.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
             grid1.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Created_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
     ))
%>
</div>
```

2nd Partial View

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.CRM_Dashboard_Requests>>" %>
 <%    
 var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "CRM_ID",fieldNamePrefix:"grid1", canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId:"SecondDiv");%>
 <div id="SecondDiv">
<%=
    grid.GetHtml( htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid1" },tableStyle: "GridTable", headerStyle: "GridHeader", columns: grid.Columns(
      grid.Column(columnName: "CRM_ID", header: "CRM ID", canSort: true),
     grid.Column(columnName: "MDLNO", header: "MDLNO", canSort: true),
     grid.Column(columnName: "EMP_Name", header: "Employee", canSort: true),
     grid.Column(columnName: "SERVICE_TYPE", header: "Service Type", canSort: true),
     grid.Column(columnName: "Requested_Amount", header: "Amount", canSort: true),
             grid.Column(columnName: "Created_Date", header: "Date", canSort: true, format: item => item.Created_Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
     ))
  %>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have tried ur suggestion, but still facing the same problem. I have seen source at run time, My div's id and htmlattribute id are same for all partialview, though I have changed it.

Comment: I have solved it. after clearing cache of browser. I think it was maintaining old cache so was giving me wrong output. Thanks your help worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use the same var name on both grids. Try var gridA and var gridB.

Comment: Sorry but still facing the same problem.